# removing strings from near, but not necessarily at, the beginning or end

Tags: awk, bioinformatics, dna-sequence

I have a file with ~10,000 strings that I need to edit. The strings are long (hundreds to thousands of characters), and I want to remove either repeating A's from near the end or T's near the beginning, but not ones in the middle. It also needs to remove whatever is between the A's/T's at the end/beginning.

Example:

```
GCTCAATCACTTGGGGACTATTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTGCACGC(500 more characters here)TCAATCACTTGGTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTGCA(600 more characters)CGCATTA(300 more characters)AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGCTAGC(1000 more characters)CGCAACTTAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACGTCGCGTCG
```

In the above example, I would be removing "GCTCAATCACTTGGGGACTATTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT" from the beginning and "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACGTCGCGTCG" from the end, but that T's and A's in the middle would be left alone.

I'm trying to do this with awk but I've never used it before and don't really know what I'm doing. I can paste a single string line and remove the A's and everything after using

```
echo -e "string" awk 'NR,$0 {gsub(/AAAAAAAAA.*$/,"");} {print}' >> SavedFile.txt
```

But that doesn't help when there are A's in the beginning, and doesn't do anything for truncating the beginning of the string. For some reason I can't get it to work with the file either, instead of having to paste in each string.

Comment: Don't get fancy until you have the basics figured out `awk '{sub(/AAAAAAAA.*$/,"");sub(^.*TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT/,"");print}' 1recordFile` where you get `1record` to work correctly is the place to start. Don't use `gsub` unless you're sure it is providing a benefit that won't ever quietly damage your data. Good luck.

Comment: what are the definitions of "near the end" and "near the beginning"? How many Ts or As constitute "repeating"? 2? 10? 1000?

Comment: Create and post sample input/output using, say, 3 lines of, say, 20 chars per line where you skip blocks of, say, 3-5 chars at a time that demonstrates your problem and we can copy/paste to test with. You can scale it to 10,000 lines of thousands of characters yourself after you get an answer - the numbers are irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want to trim your reads. For this, use a standard bioinformatics tool for read trimming, such as [Flexbar](https://github.com/seqan/flexbar), which has options to trim homopolymers: https://github.com/seqan/flexbar/wiki/Options#trimming-of-homopolymers

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's a 'simple' solution to your question because of all of the requirements, but this produces your desired outcome with your example data using GNU awk:

```
echo "GCTCAATCACTTGGGGACTATTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTGCACGC(500 more characters here)TCAATCACTTGGTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTGCA(600 more characters)CGCATTA(300 more characters)AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGCTAGC(1000 more characters)CGCAACTTAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACGTCGCGTCG" |\
awk '{
    repeats_start = match($0, /TTTTTTTT/)          # find the leftmost T repeat
    if (repeats_start < 100) {                     # if the poly T is in the first 100 bases (or however many bases you want; change to suit)
        sub(substr($0, 1, repeats_start), "", $0)  # trim everything before this location
        sub("^T+", "", $0)                         # trim the poly T until the first non-T base
    }                                              # then, for the poly A tail:
    nf = split($0, a, /AAAAAAAA+/, seps)           # split the line by poly A into an array (called "a")
    repeats_end = match($0, a[nf])                 # get the position of the last poly A
    if ((repeats_end + 100) > length($0)) {        # if the last poly A is within 100 bases of the end (change 100 to whatever)
        for (i = 1; i < nf; ++i) {                 # loop through the array
            output = output a[i] seps[i]           # and 'reassemble' the line, excluding the last non-poly A block
        }
        sub("A+$", "", output)                     # then remove the poly A tail
        print output                               # and finally, print the output
    } else {
        print $0                                   # else, print the line
    }
}'
GCACGC(500 more characters here)TCAATCACTTGGTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTGCA(600 more characters)CGCATTA(300 more characters)AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGCTAGC(1000 more characters)CGCAACTT
```

Comment: I'm confused. Isn't it enough to do: `awk '{sub(/^.{,100}T{8,}/,"");sub(/A{8,}.{,100}$/,"")}1'` ?

Comment: Your awk command doesn't seem to return the expected outcome with OP's example string, @jhnc. There are tools designed to handle this task (e.g. Flexbar, as suggested by Timur Shtatland), but OP tagged awk, so I thought I'd have a go at working out a solution